# Why LEFT JOIN results in ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value?

Tags: oracle, join

Running into a JOIN issue that doesn't stop me but I would like to understand it.

The JOIN is very basic on a number column. It works in some cases, in other it fails. There is a difference in schema definition between the two columns.

Example invented for the purpose of illustrating the problem.

**Schema**

```
ADDRESS.COUNTRYID NUMBER
COUNTRY.ID NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
```

**Join**

```
JOIN COUNTRY ON COUNTRY.ID=ADDRESS.COUNTRYID    works
INNER JOIN COUNTRY ON COUNTRY.ID=ADDRESS.COUNTRYID    works
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY ON COUNTRY.ID=ADDRESS.COUNTRYID    nonexistent LOB value
```

Please don't comment on the schema. It's not mine.

Help me understand what's causing the LEFT JOIN to fail in *some* cases. In most cases this LEFT JOIN works. In a case when LEFT JOIN fails, I tried both JOIN and INNER JOIN, and they both worked! Is this related to data storage in ADDRESS.COUNTRYID? Since INNER JOIN works, Oracle sees both ADDRESS.COUNTRYID and COUNTRY.ID as the same value. So why would LEFT JOIN on the same key fail with 'nonexistent LOB value'?

Comment: What is the rest of the query? Are you casting a value in `ADDRESS` to a `LOB` value or does `ADDRESS` have a `LOB` column that, when you left-join, is `NULL`? The answer is almost certainly somewhere else in the query but without the rest of it we can't answer.

Comment: Naturally, I can't paste complete query. I've determined there's a problem on the join because left side is a numeric field and right side is using a number in the text format. When I do TO_NUMBER() on it, things work. I would advise my question be deleted, After finding the issue, I see my invented example did not deal with the actual issue and can be confusing to others.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is inappropriate here to edit the question to add the solution. If you've found a solution you'd like to share, write an answer to the question in the space below provided for that purpose. If you don't want to do so, then either delete the question (if you don't think it will be of value to future readers) or wait to see if someone else posts an answer to it.